# PowerShell Hash table updates apply to all entries

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I am trying to update an hash table entry (Content, which is an array) where I find values - but when I try to set the value for $_ it applies to all entries in the entire hash ($hash).

```
$ContentArray = @($null, $null)
$Comparison | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Content" -value $ContentArray

    If($GetAdvancedData -eq "true"){
    $Hash| ForEach-Object{
    If ($_.VarianceType -ne  "Missing")
            {
            $_.Item
            $id = $_.id[0]
            $elem = $_.elementName
            Write-debug "Checking $elem"
            Write-debug "Checking for version $id"
            try{
                $content = Get-VersionContent -FilteredVersionID $id
                Write-debug "Content found"
                Write-debug "$content"
                # Various tests to try and set the value:
                #ForEach ($Key in $Hash.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object {$_.id -eq $id}){$Key.Content[0] = $content}
                #$Hash.Content[0] = "$content" | Where-Object {$Hash.id[0] -eq $id}
                #$Hash.DiffType = "Content"| Where-Object {$_.id[0] -eq $id}
                # $_.content.SetValue("$content","0")
                $_.Content[0] = $content
                # Reset $content to Null
                $content = $null
                }
            catch
            {
                Write-debug "No content found"
            }
            }
        }
```

I have tried setting it via a where clause based on another key value, using SetValue, and simply doing an = statement, but in each case it sets the entire hash tables content to $content - I feel as if I must be missing something obvious, but I can't see why (if I use the PowerShell ISE and debug $_ returns only the single record from the ForEach loop)

Answer (score 0):

A silly mistake-

```
$Hash.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object {$_.id[0] -eq $id} | foreach{$_.Content = $content,$null}
```

did the trick for me!